# Is the same browser equally safe on a different OS?

Tags: web-browser, internet

For example: is Chrome installed on Linux more prone to a hack (stealing logins/passwords, installing add-ons, changing something in browser...) than Chrome installed on Windows?

(I do realize that Windows is much more favorable target for intruders and considered a less secure system)

Answer (score 2):

This also depends on the implementation and programming of the browser. If a cross-platform solution was used, then the browsers might be the same across multiple platforms (leaving OS vulnerabilities aside). But if the browser was natively developed for every platform, then the chances are high, that each platform dependent version has its own weaknesses.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: the browser itself is probably not much more or less vulnerable, but most exploits will be made for the popular operating systems simply because that's probably the majority of the target systems.

Say you want to steal documents, it would look in Windows' `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` rather than `~/Documents`. Or if it tries to download and run malware, it's probably going to be a .exe file rather than something that runs on Mac OS X or Linux.

Comment: How about damaging browser or maybe installing scripts/addons in it ?

Comment: @RS I don't know, I'd assume it's mostly the same between operating systems, not considering ASLR and such.